# How to use formik checkbox when formik values have 'disabled' field with default value true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

I am working on an object which has some of the fields like

```
{
 liveDisabled: true,
 rasaDisabled : true,
 visualDisabled : true
}
```

By default when I provide this object to Formik as the initial value it renders on UI all disabled values checked but I want the opposite of this as the checkbox labels are like `Live`, `Rasa`, and `Visual` but I want when the value is true it should show the unchecked box. So for example, if user marked checked to `Live` it means to me `liveDisabled : false` but I am getting opposite.

[image]

Comment: could you please share part of code that you've written?

Comment: you could write `checked="data.liveDisabled"` to set checked state of `Field`

Comment: Have you solved your issue? I need the same : D